# Common approach to design web page components layout

Tags: css, web, html, page-layout

Starting to design web page layout from the scratch for a first time and want to know what's the best practice to set web page and all components on it measurements.
The page will have horizontal header with a navigation bar in it and a three columns beneath it.
That's what I've come up with so far:

- fixed hight in pixels for header part with horizontally aligned nav links
- fixed hight and width in pixels for web components
- components resides in a three columns (div elements) that has min-width set

Do I miss something or it's a good way to go?

PS  I'm perfectly aware of Bootstrap etc, but cannot use any framework in this project, only pure html/css

Answer (score 1):

If you know basic HTML and CSS (and possibly javaScript) I would immediately go and read up on twitter-bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

If you cannot use frameworks, then https://html5boilerplate.com/ would be a good place to start to get yourself a level playing field and a good structure :) I think that could be the perfect start for your project.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! But I cannot use any frameworks in this project, only pure html, css and js

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad and may get closed down but things to consider;

Consider using [HTML Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/) as someone else has pointed out. This isn't a framework, it's just a starting point for a HTML document, which includes a reset that will iron out any inconsistencies that you may experience when starting out. You should customise this as you need for your requirements.

In terms of layout I would consider using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which should give you the layout that you desire.

If you need to support mobile browsers, then [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are your friend. This should give you enough info to start.

As for JS, add it when you need it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: Try [Quick Slicer](http://quickslicer.sourceforge.io) for the initial layout sketch, and then edit the code, fine tune the CSS (.scss in fact), refactor the dimensions to absolute *p*i*x*els or *em*s (if necessary?), and fill the content texts to meet your needs.